# MySQL select based on the values of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to select rows based on the values of multiple columns, for example, given the following table:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3
------------------------------
1        | a        | b
2        | a        | c
3        | b        | z
```

I have no idea how to do so, and my current MySQL statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_2, column_3 IN ((a, b), (b, z));
```

This doesn't work, but I hope what I am trying to achieve is apparent. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around the column names. And you need to quote strings.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (column_2, column_3) IN (('a', 'b'), ('b', 'z'));
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83510/1)

Comment: Haha! Yes, I put them in literals, I forgot to put that in the example. I can't believe I needed parentheses. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar already mentioned the parentheses.. Or why not use logical query ;)
Which some finds it more easier...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE
(column_2 = 'a' and column_3 = 'b')
or
(column_2 = 'b' and column_3 = 'z')
;
```